# How to find the angle of line in paper js?

Tags: paperjs

In paper Js using line point find the angle and length and also, how to find the vector values for line using those vector values we find the angles, but here I am facing some problem.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify the question. I am not able to tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var pathforward=new paper.Path({strokeColor:"red",strokeWidth:2}); var point = pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length);
            var vector  = point.subtract(pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length-25));
                var x1 = pathforward.segments[0].point.x;
                var y1 = pathforward.segments[0].point.y;
                var x2 = pathforward.segments[1].point.x;
                var y2 = pathforward.segments[1].point.y;
                var m =(y2-y1) / (x2-x1);
                var angleDeg = Math.floor(Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2 -x1) * 180 / Math.PI);

              alert( angleDeg + '\xb0');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but here you go:

```
const p1 = new Point(x, y);
const p2 = new Point(x2, y2);

const angle = p2.substract(p1).angle;
```